# Laravel 5. Where String Var Clause not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello I have a question about Where this condition: if I put manually on Clause 'CLI' return items. But if I want use $code variable, return empty collection.

```
Route::get('/items/{code}/view','ItemsController@view');


public function view($code)
{
    // dd($code) return "CLI"
    $items = DB::table('items')
        ->where('code' , 'CLI')
        ->get();                       
    //return ALL Items with column "code" like CLI
}


public function view($code)
{
    // dd($code) return "CLI"
    $code = (string)$code;
    $items = DB::table('items')
        ->where('code' , $code)
        //->where('code' , 'like', $code) //NOT WORK
        //->where('code', 'like', '%' . $code. '%') //NOT WORK
        ->get();                       
    //return Items NULL
}
```

I tried pass pareameter to string, not working this. Too tried use LIKE % %.
Any suggestion please.

Comment: This really won't be reproducible.   There's absolutely no reason why these examples would produce different results if $code is in fact a string of `CLI`.

Comment: Yes, it's weird, I just have a table with a column called "code"

Comment: can you print $code value after `(string)` casting ?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will solve your problem

```
public function view($code)
{
    $items = DB::table('items')
        ->where('code' ,'=', $code)
        ->get();
}
```